# How to match numbers using regex in python in list

Tags: python, regex, numbers

I have subtitles in srt format 
I have function

```
def clearSubtitles(subtitles):
        for i in subtitles:
             if re.search("^\r$", i) != None :
                  subtitles.remove(i)
             if  re.search("^\d+\r$", i) != None:
                   subtitles.remove(i)
```

in list i have `subtitles['0\r','00:59:58,084 --> 00:59:58,888\r','Come on!\r']`

i need to match the first number of phrase  in the case `0\r` but the `^\d+\r$` matches me `timewindows(00:59:58,084 --> 00:59:58,888\r)` .. Can somebody help me ?

Comment: Don't modify your list while iterating over it, that can cause you to skip checking list members.  There are a number of alternate techniques you can use - a generator expression is probably simplest if you put all your regexps into a single boolean function.

Comment: `^\d+\r$` shouldn't match anything with `timewindows` in it. You're doing something wrong.

Comment: i remade it for one condition: `if re.search("^\r$", i) != None or (re.search(r"^\d{0,5}", i) != None:` but still not working

Comment: Your sample subtitles list has three elements in it.  Which elements are you trying to remove - just `'0\r'` or also `'00:59:58,084 --> 00:59:58,888\r'`?

Comment: blank line and '0\r' '0\r' can also be '500\r' it deltes blank lines but not numbers of phrases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I think I now understand what you're trying to remove.  Try this:

```
import re

cleared_subtitles = [subtitle for subtitle in subtitles if not re.match(r'\d*\r')]
```

This builds a new list with all elements that begin with 0 or more digits and end with \r removed.  re.match requires that the regexp match the entire string, unlike re.search.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to match lines with a single digit ?

```
re.search(r"^\d\r", i)
```

Comment: this matches me 00:59:58,084 --> 00:59:58,888\r but I need to match 0\r

Comment: you give me first re.search(r"\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\,\d{3} \-\-\> \d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\,\d{3}\r", i) this i answer on it :)